# Python-Turtle: Turning list of Strings into a working code

Tags: python, string, list, turtle-graphics

```
#There are large test lists of strings which need to be turned
# into workable code. But i keep getting 'cant assign to literal' error
from turtle import *

#Define the scripting language
'lift pen' = pu()

'lower pen' = pd()

'thin lines' = pensize(1)

'thick lines' = pensize(5)

'black pen' = color('black')

'coloured pen' = color('green')

'go to',x,y = goto(x,y)

'draw dot', s = dot(s)



def draw(test):

    home()
    total = len(test)
    list_num = 0
    while total > 0:
        print test[list_num] 
        list_num = list_num + 1 
        total = total - 1
    hideturtle()

draw(puzzle)
```

Comment: What are you expecting `'thin lines' = pensize(1)` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#example of the list being used

conundrum = ['black pen',
'lift pen',
['go to', -98, 132],
['draw dot', 10],
'lift pen',
['go to', -120, 137],
['draw dot', 10],
'lift pen',
'thick lines',
['go to', -55, 80],
'lower pen']

#Import everything from the turtle library
from turtle import *

#Define the draw function

def draw(test):
    home()
    #'total' is used as the amount of loops left
    # and amount of strings left to test
    #'current_num' is set as the current string
    # being tested starting from the first in
    # the list.
    total = len(test)
    current_num = 0
    bgcolor('black')

    # A while loop is set to run until total = 0
    #which means all strings have been checked

    while total > 0:
        #A set of if/elif statements to determine
        #what each string is and what statement
        #to use given that string

        if test[current_num] == 'lift pen':
            pu()

        elif test[current_num] == 'lower pen':
            pd()

        elif test[current_num] == 'thin lines':
            pensize(1)

        elif test[current_num] == 'thick lines':
            pensize(5)

        elif test[current_num] == 'black pen':
            color('black')

        elif test[current_num] == 'coloured pen':
            color('blue')

        #This last elif statement, tests to see if
        # it is a list rather than a string

        elif type(test[current_num]) == list:

            #As there are only 2 types of lists
            #one with 3 variables and the other with two
            #a test to determine which has 3 is run.

            if len(test[current_num]) == 3:

                # if this is true then the list is the goto() list
                # so the second variable in the list is set as x
                # and the third variable as y in goto(x,y)

                goto((test[current_num][1]),(test[current_num][2]))

            #else it is the dot() list

            else:

                 dot(test[current_num][1])

        #A final backup else statement that will print any strings that
        #dont follow with the set if statements so it can be fixed

        else:
            print test[current_num]

        #at the end of each loop the current_num is raised so the next
        #string will be tested while the total is reduced so that the
        #program can stop when it reaches 0

        current_num = current_num + 1 
        total = total - 1
    hideturtle()
    done()
```

And then all that i do is call the draw function and it works

Answer (score 2):

Things like `"hello"` are called string "literals" in python.  They represent an immutable sequence of characters.  You can't assign values to a string literal.

If you're trying to store the commands in such a way that they can be referenced and called by their string representation, try this:

```
commands = {}
commands['lift pen'] = pu
commands['lower pen'] = pd
commands['thin lines'] = lambda:pensize(1)
commands['thick lines'] = lambda:pensize(5)
commands['black pen'] = lambda:color('black')
commands['coloured pen'] = lambda:color('green')
commands['go to'] = lambda x, y:goto(x,y)
commands['draw dot'] = lambda s:dot(s)
```

Then you could access the commands with something like this:

```
commandList = [("lift pen", []), ("go to", [10, 20]), ("lower pen", [])]

for command, args in commandList:  # Loop over each command and associated arguments
    commands[command](*args)       # Call the function stored under the key given by the command with the args.
```

You'll need to parse your "large test lists of strings" into the above format first, but I can't help you with that without seeing what format it's starting out in.

Comment: thanks for the help, this is my first time posting in stack so i had a bit of trouble figuring out how to set out the post, i did figure this out though yesterday. It was actually really simple i'll post my answer